# Identifying a group that originated from a Wirtinger presentation.

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Given the group presentation
$$
\langle x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5,x_6\mid x_2x_1x_2^{-1}x_4^{-1}, x_3x_2x_3^{-1}x_5^{-1}, x_4x_5x_4^{-1}x_2^{-1}, x_1x_3x_1^{-1}x_6^{-1}, x_5x_6x_5^{-1}x_3^{-1}, x_6x_4x_6^{-1}x_1^{-1} \rangle.
$$
I would like to simplify this presentation, or even identify the group. However I am stuck on this problem for a couple of days. The group originated from a Wirtinger presentation of the link $6_1^3$ (http://katlas.math.toronto.edu/wiki/L6a5). Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The presentation simplifies to
$$\langle x_1,x_2,x_3 \mid [x_1,x_2^{-1}] = [x_2,x_3^{-1}] = [x_3,x_1^{-1}] \rangle$$
(where $[a,b] := a^{-1}b^{-1}ab$).

I cannot identify the group (whatever that means). It is an infinite automatic group that does not appear to be hyperbolic.

Comment: In the original presentation, $x_1$ commutes with $x_2^{-1}x_1x_3$. Similarly, both $x_2$ and $x_3$ appear to have non-cyclic centralisers. (Which suggests non-hyperbolicity.)

Comment: @user1729 Yes, but I think $x_1$ commutes with $x_2^{-1}x_1x_3^{-1}$.

Comment: @DerekHolt could you elaborate more on how you derived this simplified presentation? For example what substitutions did you use and which relations did you combine?

Comment: Use the relators that end in $x_4^{-1}$, $x_5^{-1}$ and $x_6^{-1}$ imply $x_4=x_2x_1x_2^{-1}$, $x_5=x_3x_2x_3^{-1}$, $x_6=x_1x_3x_1^{-1}$. Use these to eleiminate $x_4,x_5,x_6$ from the other three relators (one of which is redundant). (In fact any 5 of the 6 relators implies the 6th one.)